# java.lang.NullPointerException Error with login

Tags: java, jsp

As i want to "log in"  I always get the

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException Error

I get that it occurs when you want to access a reference type that has not been initialized but I just can't get the hang of it in my mind.

```
  Uksekaart kaart = null;
boolean allowed = false;
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
out.println(dt);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
if(request.getParameter("kaardi_id")!=null && request.getParameter("ukse_nr")!=null){
    kaart = kh.kysiUksekaart(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("kaardi_id")));
    String[] ukseList = kaart.getUksed().split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i<ukseList.length;i++){
        if(Integer.parseInt(ukseList[i]) == Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ukse_nr"))){
            allowed = true;
        }
    }
    for(veeb.AjutineLuba k:kh.kysiAjutisedLoad()){
        if(k.getKaardi_ID() == Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("kaardi_id")) && k.getUkse_nr() == Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ukse_nr"))){
            if(dt.getTime() > df.parse(k.getAlgus()).getTime() && dt.getTime() < df.parse(k.getLopp()).getTime()){
                allowed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Netbeans shows line 72

> String[] ukseList = kaart.getUksed().split(" ");

Comment: In which line do you get the exception? Did you try debugging?

Comment: Try printing stacktrace

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to this. I did the debugging part but somehow I can't see where it shows me the line or the error, it just may be Netbeans that confuses me :/

Comment: To debug, either put , logger or System.out.println() after lines and try to narrow down the problematic line

Comment: I was just changing it >P

Comment: Check the return value of `getUksed()`.

Comment: What does this return `kh.kysiUksekaart(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("kaardi_id")));` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if kaart is not null else there is a problem with your getUksed() method.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it was null but somehow my current database wouldn't let me to change it. Changed to a new one and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You getting NULL in line:

```
kaart = kh.kysiUksekaart(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("kaardi_id")));
```

Result of this line kaart = null, and when program tries to do kaart.getUksed() it can not find getUksed() method for object that is equal NULL.

I dont know architecture of all APP but try this:

```
String[] ukseList = new Array();
if (kaart != null) {
    ukseList = kaart.getUksed().split(" ");
}
```

Otherwise you need figured out why kh.kysiUksekaart(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("kaardi_id"))) gives null.